Should we separate Command and Queries into two different projects in CQRS?
Assume I need to scale up the queries in a read heavy system which uses CQRS architecture. Shouldn't we separate commands and queries into different projects then? Otherwise how we gonna do this kinda scale up if we write commands and query handlers in the same project? Any opinion?
Example:
for an example, if we have commands and queries separated into two different Web API projects in a .NET solution, then we can spawn out 10 container instances of Query API and 1  instance of Command API in a read heavy scenario.
Thanks in advance.

What would happen if you spawn 11 containers of a single API (Commands & Queries) in a read heavy scenario?

Also, what are the performance bottlenecks you want to alleviate in your scenario?

@SirRufo When it comes to cqrs, independent scalability of reads and writes is one of a major concern right? Thats why i raised this question.

Scalability happens in the infrastructure not in separating the frontend. 1. Separating write activity from read activities allows you to use the best database technology for the task at hand, for example, a SQL database for writing and a non-SQL database for reading.
2. Read activity tends to be more frequent than writing, thus you can reduce response latency by placing read data sources in strategic geolocations for better performance.
